# How do I change the text "Chat with us" in the Twilio Flex webchat client?

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I'm trying to change the text in the header pane and chat icon callout which both says "Chat with us" by default. How do I do that? I found two ways in the documentation and none of them work. 
[image: Image of twilio flex webchat client]

[image: Twilio flex webchat client]

Answer (score 4):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You need to set the `componentProps` for the component you are trying to update.

In this case, you are altering the `titleText` of the [`MainHeader` component](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/flex-webchat-basic-configuration#mainheader) so you need to format that as an object.

```
var appConfig = {
  // other config
  componentProps: {
    MainHeader: {
      titleText: 'Chat with us now!'
    }
  }
}
```

This may overwrite all the default `componentProps` though, unless you copy and merge the existing object. To avoid this, you can also use the [React default props API in Flex](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/flex-webchat-basic-configuration#react-default-props-api). To change the `MainHeader` `titleText` that would look like this:

```
FlexWebChat.MainHeader.defaultProps.titleText = 'Chat with us now by default!';
```

You can use this in the component in which you set up the `FlexWebChat` object.

All the components and props available to change can be seen in [the Flex web chat documentation here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/flex-webchat-basic-configuration#component-props).

Let me know if that helps at all.